# display security questions for registration page using angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have security questions array and i want to show the questions in a drop down. And it should not repeat the same question to another dropdown. how do i achieve using angular2/ionic2

```
 {      
  "content": [
    {
      "secQues": "what is your pet name",
      "secSeq": 1,
      "status": "A" 
    },
    {
      "secQues": "what is your nick name",
      "secSeq": 2,
      "status": "A"
    },
    {
      "secQues": "what is your name",
      "secSeq": 3,
      "status": "A"
    }
  ]      
}
```

ionic2 view

```
     <ion-item>
        <ion-label>My security questions</ion-label>
        <ion-select [formControl]="securityfaq">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let faq of secfaq" [value]="faq.secQues">{{faq.secQues}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>       

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Security answer</ion-label> 
        <ion-input type="text" [formControl]="securityanswer">
        </ion-input>
      </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*ngFor` on `secfaq` for the first choice (like you already do) and create a getter for a filtered array for the second `*ngFor`.

First, you have to store the selected item for the first choice.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>My first security questions</ion-label>
    <ion-select [formControl]="securityfaq" [(ngModel)]="firstFaq">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let faq of secfaq" [value]="faq.secQues">{{faq.secQues}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label>My second security questions</ion-label>
    <ion-select [formControl]="securityfaq" [(ngModel)]="secondFaq">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let faq of filteredSecfaq" [value]="faq.secQues">{{faq.secQues}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

In this example, `this.firstFaq` and `this.secondFaq` is the selected value of the first and second choices.

Then, you can create the getter :

```
public firstFaq:Number;
public secondFaq:Number;

get filteredSecfaq() {
    return this.secfaq.filter((faq) => {
        return this.firstFaq !== faq.secQues;
    }
}
```

In doing so, the filtered array will be automatically updated when the value of the first selector change.

Comment: thanks @noemi. I am not experienced writing filters in angular 2. could you please explain how to add filter for second selectbox

Comment: You don't have to use angular filter. `this.secfaq` is an array, so [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) is a native JS function.